# the main function in clang c99

Tags: c, clang, llvm, c99

In c99 standard, main function can be defined in two styles:

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char \* argv[])
```

But I tried (llvm 8 c99(-std=c99))

```
int main()/main()
```

and there is no warning or error.

How to understand the `main` definition in c99. and where to find the whole definition types of `main` function in clang?

Answer (score 1):

There is `int` type is default for cases where it is omited. And for function return type too. The `void` type for funtion args is equal that function have no arguments. The empty args '()' mean that arguments and its count and its types is not specicfied.

Comment: int is only default pre-c99, there being no default since then.

Answer (score 0):

Due to historical reasons, most compilers do not warn for `int main()` or just `main()` -- because that's how main() has been mostly before standardization of C.

GCC has some warning options which can detect it.

For `main()`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-declaration  -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 test.c
test.c:4:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^~~~
test.c:4:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:1: warning: old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
```

and for `int main()`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-declaration  -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 test.c
test.c:4:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int main()
     ^~~~
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:5: warning: old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
```

There has been a [bug report](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20796) in llvm whichg seems to have fixed this very recently.